# Filtering array values - return statement does not end the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have been busting my head with something which I think should be really easy, but I can't seem to fix.

I have an array which has different types of texts, which are not sorted.

So I would like to visualize only one of them, by my priority based on text type.

Here is an example of the data:

[image: Texts Array]

So I am triggering a function from the template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of elements.Event.Texts">
 <p *ngIf="textSelector(text)">{{bestText}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

And here's the function:

```
textSelector(item: any) {

if (item.Type === 'VeryShort') {
  this.bestText = item.Value;
  return true;
} else {
  if (item.Type === 'Short') {
    this.bestText = item.Value;
    return true;
  } else {
    if (item.Type === 'Medium') {
      this.bestText = item.Value;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I need only one text to be exported - by the "text type" priority.

In my case, for the example from the screenshot, I get both 'Short' and 'VeryShort' text.

Can someone give me a hint what I am doing wrong, please? I would be extremely grateful!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand what the template code does: It iterates over `elements.Event.Texts` and calls `textSelector` for **every** element. Whenever `textSelector` returns true, a `p` element is created.

I would suggest a different approach. Only call the function once because you only want one value.

```
 <p *ngIf="textSelector(elements.Event.Texts)">{{bestText}}</p>
```

This is how I would write the function. I'd use an array for setting the priority so it's a little more maintainable.

```
const order = ["VeryShort", "Short", "Medium"];

textSelector(items: any[]) {
  let bestItem;
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.Type === order[0]) {
      this.bestText = item.Value;
      return true;
    }
    if (!bestItem) {
      bestItem = item;
    } else if (order.indexOf(item.Type) < order.indexOf(bestItem.Type)) {
      bestItem = item;
    }
  }
  if (!bestItem) {
    return false;
  }
  this.bestText = bestItem.Value;
  return true;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any issues or need an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, lovre !! This worked perfectly! And also thank you very much for the detailed answer - it helped me to clear what I was doing wrong and why I did not manage to figure it out sooner. WIsh you all the best!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one. It may work

```
textSelector(item: any) {

if (item.Type === 'VeryShort') {
  this.bestText = item.Value;
  return true;
} else  if (item.Type === 'Short') {
    this.bestText = item.Value;
    return true;
  } else if (item.Type === 'Medium') {
      this.bestText = item.Value;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! Lovre posted a very good answer, which solved  my problem. Thanks again!